# We now have two cars that are plug in, and we can't charge both at same time!!! Can we "split" a circuit?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

The entire garage and one outdoor outlet are on the same 15amp breaker (110v) and it cannot handle that kind of load as each charger pulls about 11 amps. I am trying to guestimate the cost of adding an outlet, splitting a circuit (if that is even possible) or even going a step up and adding a 2 vehicle charging station at 220V.  Can this be done? Would it be outrageously expensive?

Our circuit panel is completely full, is that an issue?

Very new at this and trying to figure out what's feasible.

Comment: Can you post photos of your electrical panel?

Comment: Closing this question because asking about pricing feasibility for your specific situation cannot be feasibly entertained on an international site like this.

Answer (score 1):

If your panel supports the load, a 220v circuit will be more effective for your two vehicle charging situation. It will reduce the charging time by more than fifty percent and allow you to charge in sequence rather than simultaneously.

Outrageously expensive is a subjective concept and would have to have a reference for your level of income. You can get a quality EVSE that runs on 220v for a few hundred dollars, possibly less on the used market.

Of course, the expense of the EVSE is only a small portion of the total. A qualified electrician may charge as much or more than the cost of the unit to install a circuit. As Mr ThreePhaseEel suggests, a photo of your panel would provide additional information.

To keep your costs down, you may want to consider to install the necessary conduit and boxes yourself, drilling holes through the wall if required and installing a pull-string to facilitate wiring routing or even pull the wiring yourself. Leaving only the connections to be made will shorten the electrician's time and your costs.

Our EVs would take 44 to 48 hours to charge on a 110v circuit, yet takes fewer than 4 hours on our 10kw EVSE running on 220v. You may find you can charge less frequently than was required with a 110v circuit and also to stagger the days for the two vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

To build on fred_dot_u's answer, you can't add an outlet or upgrade the circuit size, because the actual wiring running through the wall is just not big enough to handle charging two cars at the same time. Splitting the circuit is basically just adding a new circuit, so that's not a thing either.

So, you need to add a new circuit. This will consist of converting some circuit breakers in the box to tandem breakers, (which fit 2 circuit breakers in one space) freeing up enough space for a 240V breaker. If it's not possible to convert circuit breakers to tandem circuit breakers, then you'll need a new panel.

Comment: I'm confused, if "Splitting the circuit is basically just adding a new circuit, so that's not a thing either" then how does this help :"So, you need to add a new circuit."?

Comment: I assume by splitting the circuit, you mean to move some of the outlets from the existing circuit to a new circuit. This is essentially the same as adding a new circuit, but not as good.